# scrolling in same page

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to do the same as what is here

In this site there is top static menu some if i click download ,it will take me to scroll page.

How to do this?

Comment: Also check out [other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scroll+to+div), as it has been asked already in some form or another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do something like that site, put the contents of your site in `<div>`s and set their `id` attributes. Then, do something like [this](http://djpate.com/2009/10/07/animated-scroll-to-anchorid-function-with-jquery/) to scroll to a specific `div`.

For the Javascript/jQuery stuff, you can either bind to each `<a>` element's click event, or you can just specify the `onclick="goToByScroll('insertMyDivIdHere')"` attribute in the HTML.

**Edit:**
To keep the navigation menu visible at all times, fix its position on the page. Here's the CSS  uses to accomplish this:

```
#top-bar-menu {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #210634;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #501E73;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #300B4C;
    float: left;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 24px;
    left: 0;
    line-height: normal;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 9px 0 3px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 95;
}
```

Comment: @kchau:See that site the menu bar will also come and it will navigate to particular content.I want the whole thing to be same.

Comment: To make the navigation menu stay visible, you can fix its position using CSS. See my edit...

Comment: You'll need to specify the CSS for your menu `div`, either in a separate .css file or in the `<head>` tags of your HTML page. I'd suggest doing it separately in a .css file and then including the file.

Comment: @kchau:if i click top icon inside each div,it should go to top page?How is this?

Comment: Make an element at the top of the page, like an empty `<div>` and specify the `id` attribute. Then, make your Top icon/link call the scroll function to go back to the top `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery it is very easy.

The sample code is used to scroll to the top of the page, similarly you can change the value and can go to any part of the page. Here the value is 0. 700 is the duration in which it will take you to the top portion of the webpage

```
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 700);
```

Hope this will help you : )